# How can I delete a Snapshot from DigitalOcean using Terraform?

Tags: deployment, terraform, packer

Firstly I create a Snapshot image using Packer and after I make a Droplet with a linked Domain using Terraform.

After running `terraform destroy` the Droplet and the Domain are deleted but the Snapshot created with Packer isn't.

Is it possible to delete the Snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

TF can only delete resource it created. Thus if your image has been created outside of TF, then you have to delete it manually. The alternative is to [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) the image to TF, and then delete it, but I don't see the point if you just want to delete it.